# Adwords Impressions, Clicks and Cost, how to get these?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, google-ads-api, impressions

I'm developer for marketing company and I need some help with facebook ads. I've been trying to find method for getting data AUTOMATICALLY from facebook campaign that's created by the user.

I'm trying to create script that would get data for server.

So basically I need to get Impressions, Clicks and "Cost of clicks" from each day from facebook-ad-campaigns just by having user login data (username,password) and maybe the id-number of campaign being targeted.

Also if possible I'd like to know how you can shut down campaign(when cost of clicks is greater than budged used).

Are these operations possible? Can I use PHP/FQL for it? Can I get these via Url? If I need to use FQL, what tables I need to fetch data? Anything that can be performed without manually logging to facebook? If so, could I get some example code to do it for me? If it has something to do with Access Tokens, what kind of access rights do I need to grant for it?

Answer (score 2):

Can it be possible to ask more questions in one question than you just did?  *Wow.*

Answers are in order of them asked above.  But I will not be answering any followup questions in this thread.

For most of your information can be found at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/

1. In your code, set a trigger when it has reached that value in the adstatistics, then use the Ads API to shut it down using the pause feature
2. Yes, use the Ads API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/
3. For some parts of it you can, for other parts you'll use Graph API object.
4. Yes, that's how the graph works.
5. Tables are listed in the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/
6. Nope.
7. Yep, example codes are there.
8. Yes, it sure does.
9. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions